# Low AdMob impression number in a newly released app

Tags: advertisements, admob

I posted a new game to the Play Store using AdMob. Currently I have about 1000 ad requests but only 25 impressions. Could it be because it is a newly released application?

I only have interstitial and rewarded ads, and I load them both at the beginning of the game so they have plenty of time to be ready when needed.

I found multiple posts here about the same issue, but this is specific to a newly released app. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Is it possible many players boot your game (triggering the request), but then switch away or quit the application before triggering an interstitial to display (so no impression results from the request)? This could also catch something like an automated testing bot, that installs and launches apps to confirm they boot without crashing, but then does not navigate deeper into the app to potentially encounter ads.